# InvalidPolicyDocument when POSTing to S3 bucket using presigned URLs

Tags: amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I am getting the following error whenever I attempt to post something to an S3 bucket using a POST presigned URL:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidPolicyDocument</Code>
    <Message>Invalid Policy: Invalid JSON.</Message>
    <RequestId>568TTY4KHP1SR41W</RequestId>
    <HostId>Fk5dAEIEM2Awp2+JPpuD60karubosk5crAcYCejtSZkLsyqPdFEmh4GVSEv3+tIeYSc78/OY6JY=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Below is the base64 value that figures in the `policy` field of the POST request's form data:

```
eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjoiMjAyMy0xMi0xM1QwNToyOToyMi4yMTFaIiwiY29uZGl0aW9ucyI6W3siYnVja2V0IjoiYnVja2V0LWYzOTZkOGUyIn0seyJ4LWFtei1jcmVkZW50aWFsIjoiQUtJQVgzVzZCV0NFUTZYVlI2RkcvMjAyMzEyMTIvZXUtd2VzdC0yL3MzL2F3czRfcmVxdWVzdCJ9LHsieC1hbXotYWxnb3JpdGhtIjoiQVdTNC1ITUFDLVNIQTI1NiJ9LHsieC1hbXotZGF0ZSI6IjIwMjMxMjEyVDA1MjkyMloifSxbInN0YXJ0cy13aXRoIiwiJHgtYW16LW1ldGEtcmVjb3JkLXR5cGUiLCIiXSxbInN0YXJ0cy13aXRoIiwiJHgtYW16LW1ldGEtcmVjb3JkLW5hbWUiLCIiXSxbInN0YXJ0cy13aXRoIiwiJHgtYW16LW1ldGEtcmVjb3JkLWV4cGlyYXRpb24iLCIyMDIzLTEyLTE5VDA2OjI5OjIyLjIxMTY4MSswMTowMCJdLFsiZXEiLCIkeC1hbXotbWV0YS1hdXRob3ItdGllciIsInRpZXI6MCJdLFsiZXEiLCIkeC1hbXotbWV0YS1hdXRob3IiLCJlMmIxYmZmYi05MDliLTRlMjItODY2Mi03NTk2Y2U3YzRlMTciXSxbImVxIiwiJGtleSIsImUyYjFiZmZiLTkwOWItNGUyMi04NjYyLTc1OTZjZTdjNGUxNy9mNDA2Zjg5Ny1mNmJiLTQyYzktYTRiYy1lNDhmMjU3Y2YyNjAiXSxbImNvbnRlbnQtbGVuZ3RoLXJhbmdlIiwwLDUxMi4wXV19
```

Which decodes to:

```json
{
  "expiration": "2023-12-13T05:29:22.211Z",
  "conditions": [
    { "bucket": "<valid bucket name>" },
    { "x-amz-credential": "<valid cred id>/20231212/eu-west-2/s3/aws4_request" },
    { "x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" },
    { "x-amz-date": "20231212T052922Z" },
    ["starts-with", "$x-amz-meta-record-type", ""],
    ["starts-with", "$x-amz-meta-record-name", ""],
    ["starts-with", "$x-amz-meta-record-expiration", "2023-12-19T06:29:22.211681+01:00"],
    ["eq", "$x-amz-meta-author-tier", "tier:0"],
    ["eq", "$x-amz-meta-author", "e2b1bffb-909b-4e22-8662-7596ce7c4e17"],
    ["eq", "$key", "e2b1bffb-909b-4e22-8662-7596ce7c4e17/f406f897-f6bb-42c9-a4bc-e48f257cf260"],
    ["content-length-range", 0, 512.0]
  ]
}
```

I spent time looking at the AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html) other answers but couldn't find anything useful for my case.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue. Float values for `content-length-range` is not valid json.